# TeamCity - SVN and Labelling: How to do it correctly?

Tags: svn, teamcity, labeling

I've read all the TeamCity, SVN and labeling questions in S.O. but none seams to apply to my specific problem.

Here we have the following structure on the SVN:

```
svn://server/root
              /projectA
                 /trunk
                 /tags
              /projectB
                 /trunk
                 /tags
```

On the TeamCity I've configured a SVN root for the project A like this:

```
svn://server/root/ProjectA/trunk
```

And the build process works like a charm.

However now I want to add labeling, but even setting the labeling rules as specified in the documentation or any other setting I know of, as for my latest try:

```
/ProjectA/trunk=>/ProjectA/tags
```

I get the following error:

```
jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: Labeling the path 'ProjectA/trunk' to 'ProjectA/tags/build-24' has failed with the error: svn: CHECKOUT of '/svn/root/!svn/ver/5792/ProjectA/tags': 403 Forbidden (https://server:8443)
  at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.svn.SvnSupport.throwLabelingError(SvnSupport.java:430)
  at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.svn.SvnSupport.label(SvnSupport.java:418)
  at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsLabeler.setLabel(VcsLabeler.java:45)
  at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsLabeler.access$400(VcsLabeler.java:64)
  at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsLabeler$3$1.run(VcsLabeler.java:4)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: CHECKOUT of '/svn/root/!svn/ver/5792/ProjectA/tags': 403 Forbidden (https://server:8443)
  at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:62)
  at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
  at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:623)
  at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:274)
  at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:262)
  at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doCheckout(DAVConnection.java:452)
  at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVCommitEditor.checkoutResource(DAVCommitEditor.java:468)
  at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVCommitEditor.addDir(DAVCommitEditor.java:136)
  at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.svn.SvnCopyHelper$CopyCommitPathHandler.handleCommitPath(SvnCopyHelper.java:138)
  at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCommitUtil.driveCommitEditor(SVNCommitUtil.java:139)
  at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.svn.SvnCopyHelper.doCopy(SvnCopyHelper.java:102)
  at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.svn.SvnConnection.label(SvnConnection.java:861)
  at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.svn.SvnSupport.label(SvnSupport.java:416)
```

Does anyone has any reason why this happen, or how can I set up this correctly?

In time: The user accessing the SVN does the checkout correctly as the TeamCity is configured to clean the checkout folder before every build.

Comment: do you really need to label? does not having the svn revision remove the need for labels? Especially when build no ~= revision number?

Comment: @James The point here is that we do have different build configurations and one of them we use to publish to the production environment, so, labeleing the SVN is quite important for us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would set the root like:

```
      svn://server/root/ProjectA
```

And have labeling as :

```
      trunk=>tags
```

That's how I have my VCS set up. The SVN error issue is kinda addressed [here](http://blog.alagad.com/2007/11/12/subversion-mkactivity-and-403-forbidden-headaches/).
Give it a try.

Comment: The reason to the SVN root in TeamCity to be setted this way is that if set up to the root project, TeamCity will checkout the entire tree before build. And we take measure to clean up the entire checkout folder before build too.

Comment: You can use checkout rules to limit the checkout to only include Project A.